# how to add another filter condition in zend framework query

Tags: zend-framework

This is my zend query

```
return $this->fetchRow($this->select()->where('name = ?', $geofence_name) );
```

and I want to add another filter in my query, because I want to check another condition.

please guide me.

Answer (score 10):

For `and where`

```
$select = $db->select()
    ->from('products',
        array('product_id', 'product_name', 'price'))
    ->where('price > ?', $minimumPrice)
    ->where('price < ?', $maximumPrice);
```

For `or where`

```
$select = $db->select()
     ->from('products',
            array('product_id', 'product_name', 'price'))
     ->where('price < ?', $minimumPrice)
     ->orWhere('price > ?', $maximumPrice);
```